# Check if request.getParameter contains a string value or integer

Tags: servlets

I am trying to do a search with two different values, an integer(sin) and lastName(String)
I have been able to get both saved, but how do I check if it is a string or not
Here is my code:

```
if (request.getParameter("search") != null) {
                String search = request.getParameter("search");
                int searchSin = Integer.getInteger(request.getParameter("search"));
                //If it is a string
                request.setAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployeesLastName(search));
                //else if it is an integer
                  request.setAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployeesSIN(search));

            }
```

Comment: you try parsing `search` as Integer value, and if it throws `NumberFormatException`, then it is not integer :)

Comment: Here you go with different way to check if input string is numeric https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
if (request.getParameter("search") != null) {
    String search = request.getParameter("search");
    //it is an integer
    if(isInteger(search)){
     int searchSin = Integer.getInteger(search);
     request.setAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployeesSIN(searchSin));
    }
    //else if it is a string
    else{
        request.setAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployeesLastName(search));
    }
}

// check if one string is a integer
private boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intanceof to know this

For example:

`if (myObject instanceof String) {
  // Your code here
}`

Comment: the problem here is to check if the input string is numeric :)